# For electric field between two parallel plate capacitor given by $Q/A*\epsilon_0$, how does the inverse proportionality of area make sense?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

In the above mentioned formula, how does the inverse proportionality of area make any sense? Doesn't increasing the area of the metal plate enable it to accumulate more charges thereby more electric field? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: If it could accumulate more charges, wouldn't $Q$ change also?

Comment: With $Q$ fixed, increasing $A$ *decreases* the charge density because the same amount of charge is spread out over a larger area.  A decreased charge density intuitively (and, of course, mathematically) leads to a weaker electric field. Is there some reason why you think that $Q$ should change here?

Comment: But isn't it the same charges spread over a large area? Why should electric field decrease?

Answer (score 1):

The formula that you've quoted applies to a capacitor for which the plates' dimensions are much greater than their separation.

The result follows almost immediately from Gauss's law and symmetry, which show that (except near the edges of the gap) the field runs straight from + plate to – plate. Because you've asked the question, I assume you want something other than Gauss, so I offer these thoughts...

The vast majority of points in the gap between the plates are nowhere near the plate edges, compared with their perpendicular distances, $x$ and $y$, from either plate. The field at any of these points is almost unaffected by the charge on parts of the plate that are several times further away than $x$ or $y$. The field depends on $\sigma$, the charge per unit area of plate, and we could double the plate area without affecting the field, provided that we also double the charges on each plate, in order for $\sigma=Q/A$ to be the same. If we double the area *without* doubling $Q$ we halve $\sigma$ and hence the field strength all relevant points between the plates.

Answer (score 0):

With increasing the area, the capacitance would increase, which you see from $C = \epsilon \frac{A}{d}$.

The question now is whether you apply a voltage that is then constant or if you have a fixed amount of charge on it.

If you keep a constant voltage then also more charge will accumulate with increased capacitance, $Q = CU, U = const$. The E-field will stay the same since it is $E=U/d$

If you however keep a constant charge on the plates, then the voltage and hence the field will vary, $ Ed=U=\frac{Q}{C}, Q=constant $

So taking $E = \frac{Q}{A\epsilon}$ and then changing the area, e.g. to half of its value, without changing the charge on it would result in twice the voltage and hence also twice the electric field strength.

Comment: How does that make sense intuitively?

Comment: I think it makes sense, since you have the same amount of charge on half of the area. Similarly, you could double the charge and keep the same area. In both scenarios you have twice the electrical field strength. Or are you looking for a relation between charges and electric field in a more general way, apart from plate capacitors?